# Как обратиться из скрипта объекта, к другому объекту по его Point значению в Dictionary?

Tags: c#, unity3d, словари, grid-layout

В общем, имеем мы скрипт, который прикреплен к одному объекту. Вот основной метод этого скрипта (`Tiles` — директория, куда записываются `Point` значения объектов при их создании):

```
private void OnMouseDown() {
    Point newPoint;
    TilePoint = this.gameObject.GetComponent<Grid>().GridPosition;
    //Debug.Log (TilePoint.X + ", " + TilePoint.Y + " ");       <--- Just for testing Point directions
    //NearTilePoints = new Point[7];        <---Idk maybe i will need an Array

    //Testing Points Square (3x3) from the center of clicked point
    Debug.Log (TilePoint.X + ", " + TilePoint.Y + " ");
    int i = 0;
    for (int y = TilePoint.Y - 1; y < TilePoint.Y + 2; y++)
    {
        for (int x = TilePoint.X - 1; x < TilePoint.X + 2; x++) 
        {
            newPoint = new Point (x, y);
            if (ScreenManager.Tiles.ContainsKey (newPoint)&& !newPoint.Equals(TilePoint) )
            {
                Debug.Log ("Near Points:" + newPoint.X + ", " + newPoint.Y + " ");
                    i += 1;
            }

        }
    }
    // Count of the NearPoints
    Debug.Log ("NearPoints Count: " + i);
}
```

Так вот, дальше мне нужно обратиться к объекту через его пойнт значение, чтобы проверить его на `Object.activeSelf`. Т.е. по сути мы знаем `newPoint` объекта, но как обратиться к нему с помощью этого пойнта, я не могу понять.
Какие есть способы осуществления подобного действия?

Comment: Я надеюсь, OnMouseDown вызывается не в момент движения мыши, иначе грустно.

Comment: Вызывается один раз при нажатии на объект, собственно, выдавая его пойнт позишн в консоль и позиции ближайший 8 точек.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

У вас поле процедурное или заранее созданное?
В первом случае генератор при создании поля сразу создаёт словарь, в котором ключ, например Vector2Int, а значение - ссылка на только что созданную клетку.
Во втором случае сама клетка на старте узнаёт/знает своё значение и регистрируется в какой-нибудь системе, отправляя в неё свои координаты и ссылку на себя.
Когда вам нужно получать поинт по его позиции - запрашиваете у этой системы и она ищет в словаре.

Для того, чтобы всегда иметь доступ к системе можете использовать патерн синглтон, можете в классе завести статичное публичное поле и назначать в него себя в Start(), тогда извне вы всегда через это поле сможете получить доступ к классу. Можно в клетку при генерации давать ссылку на эту систему. Вариантов много о.о

Comment: Клетка на старте получает значение (0, 0 - первый тайл, 0, 1 - второй тайл, и т.д.) и оно загоняется в словарь. А через массив возможно Point.X и Point.Y регистрировать и обращаться уже через ячейки массива? Ещё думал GameObjects[ , ] массив сделать и туда заносить созданные тайлы с их пойнт значениями в качестве x,y массива, но если честно, я не понимаю как :D

Comment: @Fan4i, да, можно и через массив. Вообще лучше уж тогда создайте статический класс, например, GridCash, в нём создаёте массив определённой размерности и два метода public static Point GetPoint(int x, int y) и public static void AddPoint(Point point, int x, int y). В первом метода проверяете чтобы x и y не вылезали за границы массива, потом получаете из массива ваш Point и возвращаете его. Во втором методе делаете то же самое, но не получаете поинт, а назначаете на эту позицию тот, что пришёл в параметре. Т.к. класс и методы статичные - они всегда доступны в любом другом классе.

Comment: В общем-то, решил вопрос так: добавил массив GameObjects[x,y], куда заносил все тайлы при их создании, затем создал для моих объектов, расположенных на тайлах, отдельный скрипт с методами SetPoint и GetPoint, где при создании они также получают пойнт позишн, а при нажатии на них получаем их пойнт позишн соответственно. Так вот, затем просто в методе OnMouseDown этого объекта обращаюсь к нужному мне тайлу в сетке через Point.X, Point.Y нажатого объекта. Может, кому пригодится :)